# Rest API C# Mapping Classes Best Approaches for complex objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, datamapper

I have a complex json object which I am deserializing to dto class in API.
While mapping this class to model class, I have tried two options:

1. IConverter interface and implementation for each class.
2. Static Mapper Class

For eg: 
Json Object:

```
{
 "Response": 
          {
        "Detail": {
            "Subject": "GE",
            "Address": {
                "CountryCode": "US"
                      }
                  } 
       }
  }
```

For this Object, Response class would have property of type Detail class,
which would have properties of type Subject ,Address etc.

Hence for 1st approach, I had to create separate class mapper for each class in source and destination.
like:

```
public class DetailMapper<DetailDto, DetailModel>:IConvert<DetailDto, 
                          DetailModel>
{
   private IConvert<SubjectDto,SubjectModel> subconvert;
   private IConvert<AddressDto,AddressModel> addconvert;

    public DetailMapper(IConvert<SubjectDto,SubjectModel> 
                       sub,IConvert<AddressDto,AddressModel> add)
       {
            subconvert=sub;
            addconvert=add;
       } 

    public DetailModel Convert(DetailDto detailDto)
      {
       //logic
       }
   }
```

When JSON Object is more complex, this pattern is less readable with more converter implementations for each class injected.

2.For 2nd approach, I created single mapper class with static methods to 
convert dto classes to model like:

```
     public class Mapper()
    {
     public static ResponseModel Convert(ResponseDto res)
     {
      //logic
     }

      public static DetailModel Convert(DetailDto det)
      {
        //logic
       }
      }
```

2nd approach seems to be providing me more readability, but I am concerned
if it is ok to use static methods for mapper class in Api.

I would like to know what are the best approaches and pattern for mapping 2 classes in c#.

Answer (score 1):

For complex and/or recurrent mappings I would consider using a tool like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), which provides you with automatic, 'same-name' mappings and allows you to easily configure general and specific mapping rules.

Comment: I am trying to do this without automapper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here, but why not deserialize the JSON string directly into the correct type, ie in .NET Core using JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JSON), or Newtonsoft has same mechanism. Any reason you cannot use this approach?